# TypeError: firebase.auth is not a function

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I am in practice in ReactJs app with Firebase. In one the exports i used auth() for the authentication the sign In route. initially it workdes in local host when i run firebase serve. But after deploying using firebase deploy while calling the function using axios post request in server side it shows error like

I initialized all req imports

```
const { admin, db } = require("../utility/admin");
const config = require("../utility/config");
const firebase = require("firebase");
require("firebase/auth");
require("firebase/firestore");
```

Error:

```
TypeError: firebase.auth is not a function
    at exports.logIn (/srv/handlers/users.js:85:6)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/srv/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/srv/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/srv/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/srv/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /srv/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/srv/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/srv/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at expressInit (/srv/node_modules/express/lib/middleware/init.js:40:5)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/srv/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem today & have the solution:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth

Firebase Auth is not a component of the Cloud Functions like Firestore, and utilizes it's own REST API endpoint.

Replace your axios.post('/') link with the appropriate identitytoolkit.googleapis.com endpoint & it should work, my friend.

Update:
Downgrading all firebase packages to a more stable version also worked for me.